# Quotient of module versus direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

It's maybe stupid question but I want to be sure about what I've learned.

Is the quotient $R$-module $R/(p^n) \simeq R/(p) \oplus...\oplus R/(p)$ in general, if not when?

I think over $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/p^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p $. And they are not isomorphic since multiplying to p, on one hand I got zero, on the other hand I did not. Am I correct?

Thank you.

Comment: $Z/p^2$ is cyclic order $p^2$ but $Z/p\oplus Z/p$ has $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ which implies order of elements is at most order $p$. They cannot be isomorphic as the generator is not being sent to the generator.

Comment: @ user45765 Thanks, what we can say about quotient $(\mathbb{Z}/p^2)/(\mathbb{Z}/p)$

Comment: Maybe you mean $(Z/p^2)/((p)/(p^2))\cong Z/p$. $Z/p$ is not embedded in $Z/p^2$. So it does not make sense to say $(Z/p^2)/(Z/p)$.